# Subdirectory as "/blogs" on firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, subdirectory, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to add a NextJs app as a subdirectory to a ReactJs app on firebase hosting? I have the main app already deployed to firebase with a domain and I want to add a NextJs app to its subdirectory "/blogs" for SEO purposes. Is this possible? If yes how? I have tried rewrites but did not get any success.

**Update**
I managed to make it work a little with the following:

---

The directory:

```
.
+-- _projectFolder
|   +-- firebase.json
|   +-- .firebaserc
    +-- Reactjs Files...
+-- nextApp
|   +-- server.js
|   +-- Nextjs files...
```

firebase.json:

```
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "blog",
      "public": "./nextApp/public",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "nextServer"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "main",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/blogs/**",
          "function": "nextServer"
        },
        {
          "source": "/blogs",
          "function": "nextServer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "source": "./nextApp",
    "runtime": "nodejs16"
  }
}
```

The code for the server.js

```
const { https } = require("firebase-functions")
const { default: next } = require("next")

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"

const nextjsDistDir = require("./next.config.js").distDir

const server = next({
  dev: false,
  //location of .next generated after running -> yarn build
  conf: { distDir: nextjsDistDir },
})

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler()
exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return server.prepare().then(() => {
    return nextjsHandle(req, res)
  })
})

/*
firebase-admin,firebase-functions
require these plugins, install them
*/
```

The next.config.js has a basePath of basePath: "/blogs"

The only problem now is somehow the next.config.js is not being detected when the build is live on firebase. None of the Image domains or the basePath is working there, these work fine locally, is there any change I need in the server.js file?

Comment: Please provide your firebase.json config file.

Comment: @Michal I tried something Like this:
`{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "main",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/blogs",
        "destination": "/nextApp/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}`
But I know this is wrong, since /blogs will redirect to the blogs homepage only, is there some way to do this better with cloud functions?

Comment: @SalmanKhan Edit your question and paste there your code.

Comment: @SalmanKhan It may be better to have the entire app as NextJS rather than one small piece. SEO bot crawlers won’t even make it to your /blogs route  with react being the entry point.

Comment: @RafaelZasas You're wrong. If he have `<a href=".../blogs">` link in main page, bot will crawl his posts there too. And there are other ways to let know crawlers to know everything about your page like `sitemap.xml`.

Comment: @RafaelZasas yes exactly that is a good point, but the problem is the app is already developed on ReactJs, so there is no other choice for now instead to only making the blogs on Nextjs.

Comment: @SalmanKhan did you ever find a 100% working method for this? Any official method to solve this from the firebase team?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the config seems to be fine. You can only add a `/**` for taking all requests.

```
{ 
"hosting": {
"target": "main",
"public": "build",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/blogs/**",
    "destination": "/nextApp/index.html"
  }
]
}
```

If this is a nextjs app i would suggest to check that you set the base path correctly -> [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath)

Comment: thanks for this, I did end up using a cloud function as a server for the Nextjs app, I can run it properly but the next.config.js file is not being loaded due to some reason when uploaded to production.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use multiple different frameworks in one project you might want to consider using [Astro](https://astro.build/).

[This video](https://youtu.be/dsTXcSeAZq8) by Fireship explains Astro really well.

Comment: Thanks, @Rafael Zasas, I have checked it out and is pretty awesome for future projects, but the app is already done, just need to make the blogs section.